# Sharepoint Workflow, unable to start when an item is changed

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

I am trying to create a workflow that is started when an item is changed, but for some reason that box is grayed out.  Does anyone have any idea why? I went through a bunch of settings and permissions, and could not find out why,

Not sure if this is potentially the issue, but the only template I have available is the three state.

Also- as an add on, is there a way to send an email to the user who updated the list, to notify them they missed a field? I don’t want to require it because there is a possibility that they do not have the info, but I want them to know they missed a field.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow using SharePoint Designer tool (info here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-workflow-HA010100591.aspx) and set the workflow start mode to whenever an user modifies that item.

Comment: I was actually at that office "how to".  The problem is I don't have access to designer... I'm doing this for my company and its blocked for some reason.  I'm guessing there's no way to do this without designer?

Comment: I guess no. Did you checked the option "This workflow will be used to approve..."? That option disables others.